# Zoom image to counteract camera movement

Tags: image, image-processing

I have two images taken in quick succession as a camera moves forward.  In order to better compare the two images, I'd like to "zoom in" on one of the images so that it would appear that the images were taken from the same location.  Assume I know the location of the camera when both pictures are taken so I know how much I need to compensate.

The problem is, I know a simple zoom isn't quite right.  What I want is something like the classic windows screensaver where it looks like stars moving past the screen.  i.e. The edges of the image are warped more than the center.  I feel like there must be an algorithm to do this but I don't know what this type of effect is called.  Could someone tell me what the proper name for this operation is and if an algorithm can perform it?

Update: I'll try and make this more clear with an example.  Suppose I put a camera on the hood of a car as it drives along and took a picture every 10ms.  I can't directly compare two successive images because in the second image, everything will be a little bit bigger (because you drove closer to it) and some things will disappear off the left or right side as you go past them.  What is the transformation you need to do to make the two images appear to have been taken from the same location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is called `Homography` or `Projective Transformation`. It keeps straight lines straight, but parallel lines may converge.